# Should each organization have one Fabric CA and manage it on their own?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a general and theoretical question in my mind. Let's say there are 3 orgs in the established fabric network. Should each of them have their own Fabric CA server and manage the CA server on their own? Or, should the Fabric CA is owned and managed by an authoritative 3rd party?
To be more specific, let's say in the food tracebility fabric network, there are several roles:farmers,distributors and government(agricultural sector). Should farmers and distributors own and manage their own CA? Or should government own and manage the CA and generate certificates for both farmers and distributors?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Either model works; it depends on the trust model you want to have in place as well as the technical capabilities of the various parties.

If people are running peers, generally speaking they would probably want to run their own Fabric CA although if there is some truly trusted party they could do it as well.  If they are just transactors on the networks (i.e. clients), you could have a central entity provide their credentials.